# Facebook audience bidding is not working: bundle status is invalid

Tags: react-native, admob, facebook-audience-network

I have a react native application on IOS, and I implemented Facebook Audience Network Bidding with Admob.

Everything looks fine; bidding requests are being sent from Admob to Facebook. But Facebook is barely responding to bid requests.

[image]

When I use the debugger, there is an error called "Bundle status is invalid" with zero documentation on the internet.

[image]

I can see test ads without any problems. I used the Ad Inspector to validate everything, and it looks fine. But production users are not able to see any Facebook ads.

SDK versions:

- FBAudienceNetwork 6.2.1
- Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 7.69.0
- GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook 6.2.1.0
- GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite 1.4.0

Is there any knowledge about this problem and what is "Bundle status is invalid"?

Comment: Where to find this "Debugger"?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/property/checklist/?property_id=yourpropertyid Replace it with your property id

Comment: Thanks for the help @ahmet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying lots of solutions, I think I found out the reason.

The problem was missing tax information.

**Step by step solution**

1. Go to monetization manager
2. Click payouts
3. Select your payment account
4. Click edit account
5. It should navigate you to the organization management page.
6. Click to payout settings
7. Now, you will see the missing tax information and an update button.
8. Download your appropriate tax form from [here](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1046259128769008?id=211412110064838)
9. Complete the form, print it, sign it then scan it.
10. Upload the completed form using the update button.
11. After few hours, it should work and you can see the "Bundle status is invalid" is gone from the debugger.

[image]

If this solution works for you, please add a comment. So I can be sure about giving the correct solution, I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: which package are you using to implement fb ads bidding, i tried expo-facebooks-ads also react-native-fbads both for these packages doesnot seems to do bidding?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It's not working. I still have the same issue.

Comment: @Changer Did you manage to solve it? I'm having the same issue, I uploaded the Tax Information still it is showing "Requesting ADs" for Placements and "Waiting for Bid Request". Also, my debuggers show the same as the Image shown in this Question.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by releasing the updated app on the store (google play store in my case), now the debugger shows all green ticks.

edit: just to clarify that I still haven't uploaded a tax info form, ill wait to see if its mandatory first.

Comment: By releasing the updated app, do you mean that you simply released the app with Facebook ads without caring about if it works without being in production?

Comment: well i had tried everything else first, it was a last resort